# Show Selected Multiple checkbox values as Text using jquery (Dynamic values)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

Show Selected Multiple checkbox values as text. This not duplicate i have searched for it.
[image]

Dynamic Form values:

```
<div class="form-group">Eligible Branch
    <select id="eligiblebranch" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" >
        <?php  $branch = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM r_branch  ORDER BY id_branch ASC");
            while ($branchresult = $branch->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $branchresult['id_branch']; ?>"> <?php echo $branchresult['branch_name']; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var checked_checkboxes = $("[id*=eligiblebranch] input:checked");
var message = "";
checked_checkboxes.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    message += + value;
    message += "\n";
});
$("#eligiblebranch1").html(message);
```

Output should be Text and has to visible here:

```
<span id="eligiblebranch1"> </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of values from multiple checked checkboxes, use jQuery map/get functions:

```
var checkedValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
    return $(el).val();
}).get();
```

This will return array with checked values, like this one: ['1', '2']

You can make it as string by using `join`

```
var checkedValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
    return $(el).val();
}).get().join(",");
```

**Or** you can use `serialize()` as well.

```
console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').serialize());
```

Comment: It worked bro thank you but how can i show the text of it. I am reached daily vote limit i will vote you tomorrow..

Comment: i am getting as 1 next line 3 next line 5  etc.. selected option id's

Comment: are you using multiselect or which jquery plugin ? It seems that there are options inside the options. if yes then try to use option:selected instead of checkbox..

Comment: Did you try to use $(this).text() instead of $(this).val() ?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Is everything okay, did you get it ?

Comment: I wrote this var text = $(this).val(); but no luck only id values are coming 1,3,4,etc..

Comment: Actually  i am using jquery plugin

Comment: Thank you very much @Loading i appriciate your answer.. I am reached voting daily limit, i will vote tomorrow.. thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124337/discussion-between-loading-and-abdul-waheed).

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the answer but it needs a little modification.

```
var checked_checkboxes = $("[id*=eligiblebranch] input:checked");
var message = "";
checked_checkboxes.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    message += value;
    message += "<br>";
});
$("#eligiblebranch1").html(message);
```

Comment: id's are coming i want to show the text in that id. what i have to change..?

Comment: So you want to show the label next to the checkbox. That will depend on how your php code is translated to html. Can you show that part of html? you can get it from the browser's console.